# How can I install specific version of pyenv?

Tags: python, installation, pyenv

Now I am using next command to install pyenv:

`curl https://pyenv.run | bash`

Obviously here I can not specify version of pyenv I want to install. But that is mandatory to use pyenv in CI tools, to make builds predictable, not to depends on latest stable versions.

So how can I install pyenv of specific version on Linux like systems(not Mac OS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could checkout the GitHub repository and get a specific version.

For this run:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
cd ~/.pyenv
git checkout tag/<version>
```

The `<version>` needs to be substituted for a valid version of the repository, e.g.  `v2.1.0`.
Don't forget to add the folder to your PATH in your shell. The official repository has more information on CLI completion https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/tree/master#basic-github-checkout

Answer (score 1):

From [pyenv-installer github](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer#installation--update--uninstallation):

> If you wish to install a specific release of Pyenv rather than the latest head, set the PYENV_GIT_TAG environment variable (e.g. export PYENV_GIT_TAG=v2.2.5).